# An optimization method for bounding the eigenvalues of a unknown non symmetric matrix

Tags: optimization, matrix, eigenvalues

Given a positive objective function $f$ that acts on a real-valued matrix $A$, I am interested in the following problem

$$\underset{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}{\text{minimize}} \quad f(A) \quad \text{subject to} \quad b \leq \text{Re}(\lambda_j) \leq a, \quad j=1,2,...n \ ,$$

where $\lambda_j \in \mathbb{C}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, and $\text{Re}(\cdot)$ is the real part of a complex number. What optimization methods are available for approaching this task? I know there are several techniques for bounding the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices, but I wonder what happens in the non symmetric case (my $A$ is not necessarily symmetric)?

- This question was posted originally in the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316457/144053) forum.

Comment: Can you say anything about $A$?

Comment: Unfortunately no, @Richard. $A$ does not have any particular structure.

Comment: Can you provide how $f$ looks like?

Comment: Yes. $f$ could be as simple as $|AX-Y|_F^2$ where $X, Y$ are fixed known matrices and $|\cdot|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is $n$ generally or what is an upper bound for $n$? Further, how good does the result need to be? Can you do an approximation if it’s significantly faster to compute or do you really need to try and get the global optimum for a potentially general matrix $A$ (meaning no assumed structure)?

Comment: $n$ is on the range of hundreds. What kind of approximation? I am fine with approximations since $f$ could be more involved (and there might be additional non-linear non-convex constraints)

Comment: Is the set described by the constraints even convex? Is it indeed connected?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be done with a semidefinite program by adding a multiplicative slack variable.  Basically,

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\min\limits_{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} &&f(A)\\
\text{st} && b I \preceq PA + A^TP \preceq a I\\
&& P \succ 0
\end{array}
$$

Essentially, this is the Lyapunov stability condition.  Of course, this problem is a pain to solve because the $PA$ term is quadratic, so we effectively have a nonlinear semidefinite program.